# Creating a leaderboard from a mySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL table containing multiple entries from several users (identified by userid). A full row contains userid,location, species and weight. I want to have a leaderboard, containing heaviest weight and corresponding location for each user for a certain species.

I tried:

```
SELECT userid, location, f_weight_i FROM eac.catches WHERE f_weight_i = (SELECT MAX(f_weight_i) FROM eac.catches) AND species='32' GROUP BY userid ORDER BY f_weight_i
```

but it didn't return any rows.

I also tried this, and it returned the overall best weight:

```
SELECT userid, location, f_weight_i FROM eac.catches WHERE f_weight_i = (SELECT MAX(f_weight_i) FROM eac.catches)
```

How can I get best weights for each user, for every species?

Comment: "best"= max weight.

Comment: Yeah, sorry! You may got that we're talking about fishing and for us (fishermen) "heaviest fish"="best fish". ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an inline view (MySQL calls it a derived table) to get the maximum f_weight_i for each user for a given species.

Then join the result from that back to the table to get the whole row.

Like this:

```
  SELECT c.userid
       , c.species
       , c.location
       , c.f_weight_i
    FROM eac.catches c
    JOIN ( 
           SELECT w.userid
                , w.species
                , MAX(w.f_weight_i) AS max_f_weight_i
             FROM eac.catches w
            WHERE w.species = '32' 
            GROUP BY w.userid, w.species
         ) m
      ON m.max_f_weight_i = c.f_weight_id
     AND m.userid         = c.userid
     AND m.species        = c.species
   ORDER BY c.f_weight_i DESC
```

To get the results for all species, remove the WHERE clause from the inline view query (derived table `m`).

Comment: I feel like the inner query is all he needs.

Comment: @KiNeTiC sometimes feelings can be like that

Comment: @KiNeTic: The inline view gets the maximum weight.  But that doesn't get the value of the `location` column from that row with the maximum weight. If OP didn't need to `location` column, then the inline view query would be sufficient.

Comment: That does the job. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JackSanders Consider upvoting answers which you consider to be useful. If the issue is resolved, mark the accepted answer as 'accepted'.

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you for hint! It's my first contact with StackOverflow, still need to learn basics. Unfortunately, my vote does not count, my reputation is zero :(.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to create a test table, but this should get you close.

```
SELECT userid, location, species, f_weight_i
FROM eac.catches INNER JOIN
    (SELECT userid, species, MAX(f_weight_i) AS f_weight_i
    FROM eac.catches GROUP BY userid, species) AS tmp
ON eac.catches.userid = tmp.userid
    AND eac.catches.species = tmp.species
    AND eac.catches.f_weight_i = tmp.f_weight_i;
```